# Page number in jsreport

Tags: jsreport

Is it possible to display page number in [jsreport](http://jsreport.net)?
I couldn't find this either on the homepage of the tool nor by googling.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you ask for page numbers in a pdf report created by phantom-pdf recipe...

You can use special tags `{#pageNum}` and `{#numPages}` in template.phantom.header for this:

```
<div style='text-align:center'>{#pageNum}/{#numPages}</div>
```

Note you can use also javascript in header/footer to customize visibility or value of the page numbers.

```
<span id='pageNumber'>{#pageNum}</span>
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById('pageNumber');
    if (parseInt(elem.innerHTML) <= 3) {
        //hide page numbers for first 3 pages
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

[Documentation here](http://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf)

**UPDATE 2022:**
jsreport now uses primarily [chrome](https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf) for generating pdf. You can now add page numbers using [native headers](https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf#native-headers-and-footers) or in complex cases using [pdf utils](https://jsreport.net/learn/pdf-utils)

pdf utils based header playground example can be found [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/admin/kMI4FBmw).

Comment: Thank you Jan for your answer. Unfortunately I've tried `<div style='text-align:center'>{#pageNum}/{#numPages}</div>` in jsrender playground and it didn't work. #pageNum #numPages were not replaced by numbers

Comment: Can you share a link? It seems to work for me [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/vB5hrpcS-t/2)

Comment: @JanBlaha I am not using stored templates rather using dynamic templates, Page numbers are not working as expected when tried with above samples. Is there any sample code for dynamically applying CSS, pagination and specifying custom font style?