# JsReport Recipe ChromePdf page number

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jsreport

I have been creating a PDF in asp.net Core with JsReport plugin.
Everything is working well except I can't print the page number and total page number in my pdf file.

I was following the steps in this doc https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-aspnetcore to setup controller in my asp.net Core project.

I have seen some similar questions and answers posted in stackoverflow and tested them but it does not solve my problem.

Question 1: [JsReport Page Number with Chrome-pdf recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113255/jsreport-page-number-with-chrome-pdf-recipe)

Question 2: [Page number in jsreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326567/page-number-in-jsreport)

```
Page&nbsp;<span class="pageNumber"></span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;<span class="totalPages"></span>
```

I have also tried this in my Razor view but I can't see any number in my pdf.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the example [here](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-example-webapp/blob/master/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L41)

The main requirements are described in the [documentation](https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf#native-headers-and-footers).

> Remember that in order to show the header/footer you need to activate the displayHeaderFooter option first and add some top, bottom margin to the template in order to give the page some space to show the header/footer.

This translated into the asp.net core integration

```cs
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public async Task<IActionResult> InvoiceWithHeader()
{
    var header = await JsReportMVCService.RenderViewToStringAsync(HttpContext, RouteData, "Header", new { });
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature()
        .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
        .Configure((r) => r.Template.Chrome = new Chrome {
            HeaderTemplate = header,
            DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
            MarginTop = "1cm",
            MarginLeft = "1cm",
            MarginBottom = "1cm",
            MarginRight = "1cm"
        });
    return View("Invoice", InvoiceModel.Example());
}
```